# Why are chip designers called "triangle pushers"?

Tags: history, chip-design

I heard chip designers being described as "triangle pushers," the idea being that somehow the logic on the chip was formulated by arranging triangles on the silicon in certain ways. How does this work? I don't understand how triangles can be arranged to create digital logic or why the shape of a triangle would be important.

Comment: Been in that industry for 25+ years and never heard that term.

Comment: Who calls them that, exactly?

Comment: Did they used to give out little sample triangles to get you hooked?

Comment: Don't you see the schematic in the logo for this site?  It's obviously a _triangle_ that is _pushing_ against a wall.  It's right there in red and white.

Comment: Well, I worked in the same RCA office with the guy who designed the industry's first computer layout software for ICs, and I don't recall this term being used.  I do vaguely recall that the computer "drawing" was done largely with overlaid triangles, so I'd guess that's what's being referred to, if the term is at all real.

Comment: It looks like some functions in computer graphics rendering are called "triangle pushers" since triangles are used for polygonal 3D rendering. I couldn't find any references to "triangle pusher" being used to describe a person. But the Internet does not actually know all.

Comment: How about "tri-wranglers"? :D

Comment: I would have pulled out of the ether that it was due to the symbols for the `OR` logic gate.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Early masks for the creation of layers on an IC were created by a photographic process that involved exposing the original photographic plate through a mechanically controlled triangular aperture. Hence triangle pusher.

The light source was fixed above the aperture, the plate was moved xy underneath. The point of a triangle was that additive it could give any orthogonal geometry required.

There were no laser printers back then.

Comment: @oldfart obviously before your time then :)

Comment: @Solar Mike No I remember rubylith ;).

Comment: Can you elaborate how a triangular aperture would be of any benefit? It seems to me that it would give uneven exposure depending on orientation of the triangle relative to direction of travel.

Comment: @Transistor I'm just guessing, but the aperture in optics is typically in the focal plane, not image plane. Therefore, the projected image is the Fourier Transform of a triangle. If the blades are rounded a bit you'll soften it more. This is fairly typical in old cameras (the "bookeh" comes out as hexagons).

Comment: Is this from your own experience, or can you provide any reference for the phrase "triangle pusher" in this sense? Google results for the phrase are unfortunately polluted with nail care products. I'd be interested to learn more about this old manufacturing process.

Comment: I also searched Google before putting the answer up with no sensible result as you have pointed out. This is from personal experience. But goes back 40 yrs. I worked for an IC design consultancy. Our CAD files created on a Calma system would be broken down to triangles and then sent to a specialist photolith company to produce the mask masters and also coloured photo enlargements of each layer for manual checking. I have no direct connection of the term "triangle pusher" to this process it was not used in our company. But you have to admit that the coincidence is too significant to ignore.

Comment: @trentcl If you have any better ideas I would be prepared to listen to them.

Comment: @RoyC Nope, and I appreciate you sharing :) I had never heard "triangle pusher", though "polygon pusher" is common parlance for layout artists. I wonder if there might be some cross-contamination, perhaps "triangle pusher" started out in manufacturing and inspired the other phrase, if it did indeed come from a physical device with a triangular aperture.

Comment: I've never heard of an optical pattern generator with a triangular aperture. I've only heard of rectangles, usually rotating. ([examples](http://www.cnf.cornell.edu/doc%5Cchoosing%20an%20optical%20pattern%20generator%20at%20the%20CNF%20v2.pdf))  Considering 99% of IC patterns will be rectilinear, the whole photolithography process is set up for masks with it (e.g. quadrupole illumination), although by that time most masks were e-beam. Making mask patterns out of triangles sounds strange to me, and twice as much work.

Comment: How come this answer has upvotes?  It seems to be basically wrong.

Comment: Agree totally with @uhoh - The old mask maker I recall using in the mid-80s (running from a PDP-11 with paper tape to boot it up) was definitely rectangle-only, no triangles.

Comment: @Fattie where exactly is this wrong.

Comment: @Jon Custer modern ebeam mask writers use both rectangular and triangular beam shapes to achieve the required pattern. The advantage of a triangle is that you can create any shape polygon by combining triangles.

Comment: @RoyC - sure, but your answer explicitly stated ‘early masks’, so I went for early mask makers. It was a big deal when non-rectangular machines were available.

Answer (score 33):

They are called "polygon pushers".

> #### [polygon pusher: n.](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/P/polygon-pusher.html)
>
> A chip designer who spends most of his or her time at the physical layout level (which requires drawing lots of multi-colored polygons). Also rectangle slinger.

Comment: +1 for "polygon pusher." Never heard "triangle pusher" but I imagine the etymology is the same.

Comment: [Here is a layout of an NMOS NOR gate as you might see it in layout editing software.](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:NOR_gate_layout.png) The different colors of the shapes correspond to different metal layers of the process.

Comment: @trentcl that's CMOS, not NMOS. Note there are transistors on both sides of the output and no resistors.

Comment: @JohnDvorak Yes, you are right. The Wikipedia article in which it's linked is misleading, and semiconductors aren't my field, so I didn't notice. Thanks!

Comment: In what sense is it misleading? Feel free to edit it yourself.

Comment: On [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOR_gate), the picture was in the same row with the ones of which the text says "The diagrams above show" an NMOS gate. I probably had already edited it when you looked at the page.

Answer (score 2):

In computer graphics, a poly-pusher (short for polygon-pusher), is a system that uses a brute force approach to simply draw as many polygons as possible, as opposed to more intelligent systems that try to figure out things like which triangles are visible, or ray-tracing.
Historically, brute-force has always won when compared to more complex systems. The winning philosophy seems to be, "do the simplest thing possible, as fast as possible.". Thus most modern-day graphics cards are "poly-pushers".

Not heard the term used for a hardware engineer, but it's possible that someone who believes in simple, fast, hardware, might be called a "poly-pusher", or maybe a "poly-pusher-pusher" :-)

Comment: This was also the etymology I thought of as I'm sure I've heard it used in the context of NVIDIA's or ATI/AMD's graphics chips engineering teams.

Comment: @downvoters: please provide feedback as to why you down voted

Comment: @gatorback Because this is a nonsense answer and the modern use of the word related to drawing polygons has _nothing_ to do with the use of the word in the ASIC industry 40 years ago. The only reason this even has a positive score is because it ended up on the hot network list, attracting kids from all over SE. This took it from 100% negative score to lots of upvotes. The final sentence even explicitly says "Never heard the term used for a hardware engineer".